# videojs.record , trying to autostart the video

Tags: jquery, videojs-record

I am trying to autostart the camera in the browser(chrome) using the below API

https://github.com/collab-project/videojs-record

The problem is (like shown in the demo), it shows a icon and on click of that it start the camera. But I want to start it by default as soon as screen opens. I tried .start() method also tried .retrySnapshot() but they did not worked. Any pointer will be helpful. Thanks !

Demo 
https://collab-project.github.io/videojs-record/examples/video-only.html

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Found the way. You have to call this function.

```
player.record().getDevice();
```

Comment: Thanks mate. I tried to start auto record after device is ready. If you add
`player.record().start();`
 in the `deviceReady` event, record will start record automatically.